# How to choose dst coordinates for cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)

Tags: python, opencv, perspective

I have been searching around for quite a while, but still could not understand how destination points are chosen for bird eye view transformation. My understanding is that `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)` calculate the homography matrix (or warp matrix) by mapping points `src` from one image plane to the corresponding points `dst` on another image plane. Taking the example of converting the front view of car lane to birds-eye view, `src` is generally the coordinates of 4 vertex of the region of interest, but my question how to choose `dst` given `src`? I have been thinking very hard about this in the following case, please give me any help.

Here is a concrete [example](https://nikolasent.github.io/opencv/2017/05/07/Bird%27s-Eye-View-Transformation.html):
the original code in the post:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

IMAGE_H = 223
IMAGE_W = 1280

src = np.float32([[0, IMAGE_H], [1207, IMAGE_H], [0, 0], [IMAGE_W, 0]])
dst = np.float32([[569, IMAGE_H], [711, IMAGE_H], [0, 0], [IMAGE_W, 0]])
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst) # The transformation matrix
Minv = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(dst, src) # Inverse transformation

img = cv2.imread('./test_img.jpg') # Read the test img
img = img[450:(450+IMAGE_H), 0:IMAGE_W] # Apply np slicing for ROI crop
warped_img = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (IMAGE_W, IMAGE_H)) # Image warping
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(warped_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)) # Show results
plt.show()
```

Here is the test image:
[image: test image]

roi image:

[image]

and output transformed bird eye view image:

[image].

What really confuses me is how `dst` and `src` are choose in this example? `dst = np.float32([[569, IMAGE_H], [711, IMAGE_H], [0, 0], [IMAGE_W, 0]])`, especially 569, 711, initially I thought that was the x coordinates of ego lane markers at the top, but it was not. when I change 569, 711 to x coordinates of ego lane markers (592,692) at the top. Following is the comparsion. You may see that when I changed (569, 711) to (592,692) in `dst`, then parallel peroperty is getting worse. [image]

Could you please help me understand how `src`  and `dst` can be properly chosen?

**Update**:
Here is scr and dst points visualiztion, could anyone help me understand how are points chosen? I am desperate to know. [image]
dst matches perfectly the output bird eye view:
[image]

Comment: Dst coordinates are just the corners of any rectangle that defines your desired size for the output. Of course the coordinates in dst must be in the corresponding corners to those in src. Usually one selected an output size whose aspect ratio is the same as the cropped input. If your coordinates are not on a rectangle, then the lines will start to diverge as you are not going from a rectangle to a rectangle and so not preserving perspective distortion.

Comment: @fmw42 I add updated information to the question post, could you please help me understand how src and dst have been chosen in this case? the chosen src and dst do not form rectangles, but it works very well.

Comment: Did you draw the blue lines?  Where did they come from?  Are these your images or someone else's? It is possible they had a camera model and could them rotate the model to ground level. When I used to do this kind of thing, we had a ground map to which we corrected things. That is the other way. The bottom two blue cornes make no sense projected on to that image. But they would make sense if someone had a ground map or a 3D camera model knowing how the camera was pointing. If the latter, then the transformation to downloading could be computed and the src points projected to ground level

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, the blue lines were drawn by me. It matches perfectly the bird eyeview.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a homography that makes the converging lines on the road become parallel. You could take 4 points on src that are on top of the lines and map them to the corners of a rectangle.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not generate a result as good as one in my question post. Could you please help me understand how ````src = np.float32([[0, IMAGE_H], [1207, IMAGE_H], [0, 0], [IMAGE_W, 0]])
dst = np.float32([[569, IMAGE_H], [711, IMAGE_H], [0, 0], [IMAGE_W, 0]])```` are chosen? I am desperate to know that. Please notice that netiher dst nor src defines a rectangle.

Comment: I add updated information to the question post, could you please help me understand how src and dst have been chosen in this case? the chosen src and dst works very well. Thank you very much, happy thanksgiving.

Comment: Looking at your reference, it says "To find correct transformation, source and destinations points a test image with flat and straight road can be used for perspective measurements."  That seems to imply they had a ground view image to which they found conjugate control points that helped them figure out where on the src image to place the bottom two corners.

Comment: If they did not have some other image, then they just slid the bottom two points until the lines became vertical and parallel.

Comment: @fmw42 Let's say that they did not have some other image, how would you determine the width of the bottom two points? Sincere we know that the bottom two points will be symmetric around the frame center as that is where the camera is located. If we could not determine the width of the bottom two points, then there will be too many possibilities to find these bottom two points to make the lane marker parallel in bird eye view image.

Comment: Trial and error. Keep adjusting symmetrically until the lane lines become parallel. If the points are too far apart, the lines with diverge. If too close, the lines will converge. When just right spacing, they will become parallel.

Comment: Thank @fmw42 so much for your precious time teaching me online here. I am very grateful for your help. Your guidance helped me out. I got it to work with Trial and error. Thank you so much.